# How to solve a system of linear equations over the nonnegative integers?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, sympy, integer-programming

Given a linear system `Ax = b`, where matrix `A` and vector `b` have integer values, I want to find all **nonnegative integer** vectors `x` that solve this equation.

So far, I have found some techniques such as the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) or the [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form) of a matrix to find integer solutions, and I guess I could then use a linear solver to find nonnegative solutions. Is there a library that could make this easier?

Python solutions would be ideal, but if a library exists in another language I want to know about it.

Comment: Have you tried Numpy or SciPy?

Comment: @Julio Daniel Reyes Both of those can solve linear systems with floats and do optimization, but not the specific thing I asked in the question AFAIK.

Comment: If A is invertible, then there is only one solution, which you can find and check for being all-integer.  But I'm guessing your matrix is non-invertible (and possibly not even square).

Comment: Related: [Get all positive integral solutions for a linear equation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46013884#46019800), [finding integer solutions (diophantine) to linear systems with numpy/sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37101110).

Comment: Actually, there is a problem with your question which comes from linear algebra. If a matrix equation have a solution it's either the only solution or there are an infinite number of solutions. So, in the 2nd case it's problematic to find all solution as vectors, not as a formula.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this using integer programming, defining a non-negative integer decision variable for every x value you have. Then you could solve the problem with constraints Ax=b and objective 0, which searches for any feasible integer solution to your system of equations.

This can easily be implemented using the pulp package in python. For instance, consider solving the following system:

```
x+2y+z = 5
3x+y-z = 5
```

You could solve this in pulp with:

```
import pulp
A = [[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, -1]]
b = [5, 5]
mod = pulp.LpProblem('prob')
vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('x', range(len(A[0])), lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
for row, rhs in zip(A, b):
    mod += sum([row[i]*vars[i] for i in range(len(row))]) == rhs
mod.solve()
[vars[i].value() for i in range(len(A[0]))]
# [1.0, 2.0, 0.0]
```

This identifies a feasible integer solution, x=1, y=2, z=0.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I need. Is there any way to get all of the solutions with pulp? (In my specific application there are always finitely many solutions)

Comment: @while1fork, one approach to find all the solutions is by adding a constraint to the model after each solution is found that removes that solution from the feasible region, and then solving it again. You can repeat it in a while loop and stop when the model becomes infeasible. This is inefficient if you model is large or there are a ton of alternative solutions.Writing such an integer cut constraint to exclude only one solution can be tricky, and it's easy for binary programming -- for integer programming, see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.5329&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

If at least one nonnegative integral solution of `Ax=b` exists, then **integer programming** should be able to find it. The set of all nonnegative integral solutions can be found via the null space of `A`.

---

#### Example

Using the `A` and `b` in Erwin's answer:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> A = Matrix([[ 1, 2, 1],
                [ 3, 1,-1]])
>>> b = Matrix([20,12])
```

compute the null space:

```
>>> A.nullspace()
[Matrix([
[ 3/5],
[-4/5],
[   1]])]
```

The null space is 1-dimensional and its basis vector is *rational*-valued. Using the particular solution `(2,8,2)` that Erwin found, the set of all real solutions is a **line** parametrized as `(2,8,2) + t (3,-4,5)`. Since we are interested only in nonnegative integral solutions, we intersect the line with the nonnegative octant and then with the integer lattice, which produces `t ∈ {0,1,2}`. Hence, if:

- `t=1`, we obtain the solution `(5,4,7)`.
- `t=2`, we obtain the solution `(8,0,12)`.

Note that these are the 3 solutions Erwin found using Z3.

---

However, it is much harder when the dimension of the null space is higher than 1. Take a look at:

- Jesús De Loera, [The many aspects of counting lattice points in polytopes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Edeloera/RECENT_WORK/semesterberichte.pdf), 2005.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Z3 model. [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) is a theorem prover from Microsoft. The model is very similar to the MIP model proposed earlier.

Enumerating integer solutions in a MIP is not totally trivial (it can be done with some effort [[link]](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2013/03/there-are-293-ways-to-make-change-for.html) or using the "solution pool" technology in advanced MIP solvers). With [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) this is a bit easier. Even easier could be to use a Constraint Programming (CP) solver: they can enumerate solutions automatically.

Here we go:

```
from z3 import *
A = [[1, 2, 1], [3, 1, -1]]
b = [20, 12]
n = len(A[0]) # number of variables
m = len(b)    # number of constraints

X = [ Int('x%d' % i) for i in range(n) ]
s = Solver()
s.add(And([ X[i] >= 0 for i in range(n) ]))
for i in range(m):
    s.add( Sum([ A[i][j]*X[j] for j in range(n) ]) == b[i])

while s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
    sol = [s.model().evaluate(X[i]) for i in range(n)]
    forbid = Or([X[i] != sol[i] for i in range(n)])
    s.add(forbid)
```

It solves

```
x0+2x1+x2 = 20
3x0+x1-x2 = 12
```

The solutions looks like:

```
[x2 = 2, x0 = 2, x1 = 8]
[x2 = 7, x1 = 4, x0 = 5]
[x2 = 12, x1 = 0, x0 = 8]
```

We can print the final model so we can see how the "forbid" constraints were added:

```
[And(x0 >= 0, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0),
 1*x0 + 2*x1 + 1*x2 == 20,
 3*x0 + 1*x1 + -1*x2 == 12,
 Or(x0 != 2, x1 != 8, x2 != 2),
 Or(x0 != 5, x1 != 4, x2 != 7),
 Or(x0 != 8, x1 != 0, x2 != 12)]
```

Comment: What if the null space of `A` contains a rational-valued ray in the nonnegative orthant? In that case, if there is one integral nonnegative solution, then there are infinitely many integral nonnegative solutions. How does Z3 handle that? Does it time-out?

Comment: It will behave as one would predict: the loop will not terminate (well, at some time you will run out of memory) and keep on producing new solutions. Just add a counter and stop when you have seen N solutions.

Answer (score 0):

See `zsolve` method of `4ti2` package in [here](https://4ti2.github.io).